# Access Web Application Spring Bean in a standalone application

Tags: spring

I have a spring web application deployed on to tomcat. One of the bean class in the web application war has a static ArrayList. I have another standalone java application, through which I want to access this static ArrayList and iterate. Can anyone help me on the same?

Comment: You can not access directly. You should use any other services like web service.

Comment: Thanks Kanagaraj. Any example for what you stated?

Comment: We always use web service but its in diff location and all are web app.in your case both in same machine some other better way may there. Search it. Else i will give you any option.

Comment: @Kanagaraj - Can we achieve this using beanfactorylocator in spring framework?